# Safe removal of flash disk

Tags: debian, command-line, eject

In Ubuntu 16.04, I try to safely remove the flash disk from the command line. When I run the following script (from the [Eject / safely remove vs umount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178638/eject-safely-remove-vs-umount)):

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb1
udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb1
```

It says:

```
Error powering off drive: Error opening /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/remove: No such file or directory (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

When I type these commands from the keyboard, I don't get the error.

Why, and how should I make the script running?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the script and the manual typing might be a timing issue. If so, add a delay between the two commands.

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb1
sync
sleep 1
udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: If the problem is timing, then `&&` doesn't make any difference. The difference between `;` (or newline, they're different ways of writing the same thing) and `&&` is that with `&&`, the second command is executed only if the first succeeded. The timing of the commands is not affected.

Comment: `&&` did not help

Comment: ,@user31264 did you try the commands above with the sync and sleep?