# unmount SD card makes file checksum change

Tags: mount, automounting, sd-card, unmounting, checksum

I have an SD card mounted by Lubuntu at `/media/$USERNAME/COREELEC/`

I need to copy a file from one directory to another and rename it. However if I check the `md5sum` (or `sha512sum`) after I `unmount` it and mount it again, it's different.

- Why is the checksum different after mounting again the SD card?
- Is there anything I can do to make it be the same again?

**Steps to reproduce it (assuming there is an SD card mounted already by the OS)**

Copy the file and check the `md5sum` for both the original and the copied files:

```bsh
$ # copy the file from the original directory to the desired directory
$ cp /media/$USERNAME/COREELEC/device_trees/gxm_q201_3g.dtb /media/$USERNAME/COREELEC/dtb.img
$ # checksum of the original file
$ md5sum /media/$USERNAME/COREELEC/device_trees/gxm_q201_3g.dtb 
fd97f3d36cbb53cbdd59b53603f45913  /media/$USERNAME/COREELEC/device_trees/gxm_q201_3g.dtb
$ # checksum of the file I copied
$ md5sum /media/$USERNAME/COREELEC/dtb.img 
fd97f3d36cbb53cbdd59b53603f45913  /media/$USERNAME/COREELEC/dtb.img
```

Unmount the SD card

```bsh
$ # check which drive to unmount
$ df -aTh | grep COREELEC
/dev/mmcblk0p1        vfat             512M  170M  343M  34% /media/$USERNAME/COREELEC
$ # unmount the SD card
$ umount /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

Unplug the SD card by hand and plug it again by hand waiting for the Operating System to automatically mount it.

Then check the `md5sum` (see **now the checksum is different**):

```bsh
$ # checksum of the copied file (NOW DIFFERENT!)
$ md5sum /media/$USERNAME/COREELEC/dtb.img 
c8e06c372926719c0a0dac2d5b0f6ab5  /media/$USERNAME/COREELEC/dtb.img
$ # checksum of the original file (STILL THE SAME!)
$ md5sum /media/$USERNAME/COREELEC/device_trees/gxm_q201_3g.dtb
fd97f3d36cbb53cbdd59b53603f45913  /media/$USERNAME/COREELEC/device_trees/gxm_q201_3g.dtb
```

Comment: fix: change SD card. That's the symptom of a failing SD card. It's silent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The md5 checksums of two files are different only if their content are different. You can confirm this by comparing them with `cmp` or `diff` command.

Their could be several reasons for the copy operation not working correctly:

1. Unplugging sdcard before the disk cache is flushed. You can try using [udiskctl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178648/187585).
2. Filesystem corruption. You can try reformatting the card.
3. Hardware failure.

Comment: My scenario was number 3: hardware failure. Replacing the unbranded/cheap SD card with a high quality one from a popular brand did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

System does not write all data until media is going to be unmounted. 
This is a common behaviour with removable (usually slow and flash memory) media because system try to limit writes.

*Visually*, you can notice file manager (PCManFM if I well remember...) warns you about wait for the unmounting process (if you have a LED for the SD card reader, it will blink like a hell)

---

**EDIT1:** you can check/prove my theory by using the `sync` command which flush file-system cache